# Кросс-компиляция Python3 для Линукс

Tags: linux, python-3.5, кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь сделать кросс-компиляцию Python 3.5.5 на Raspberry, чтобы потом перенести на промышленный контроллер (в котором Линукс). Инструкция по вот этой ссылке - http://idiip.jiinii.com/cross-compile-python-3.html 
На последнем шаге в командной строке выдает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ensurepip._main()
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 209, in _main
default_pip=args.default_pip,
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
_run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 40, in _run_pip
import pip
File "/tmp/tmph_r0korw/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmph_r0korw/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmph_r0korw/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmph_r0korw/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in <module>
File "/home/pi/Python-3.5.5/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/pi/Python-3.5.5/build/lib.linux-arm-3.5/_ctypes.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Makefile:1048: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install»
make: *** [install] Ошибка 1
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Знаний пока не хватает.

Comment: тулчейн какой-то используете или чистый cross-gcc?

Comment: @eri , я пока в этих терминах слабо ориентируюсь (просвятите в двух словах). Просто как написано в ссылке так и делаю.

Comment: у питона море зависимостей. без SDK собирать его можно разве что под родную ось (для дебиана на дебиане той же версии). да и с sdk иногда тяжко. 3,7 под pocky скомпилить не удалось почистому)

Comment: @eri, порекомендуйте тогда SDK.

Comment: Sdk это набор от производителя железке с компилятором и всякими программами, предустановленными на устройство. Тулчейн это набор из компилятора, стандартных биьлиотек и системы сборки. В сдк к нему ещё набор программ обычно идет. Если устройство на дебиане, то надо найти или собрать сдк той же версии для дебиана. Если на опенврт, то сдк на сайте опенврт. Ёкто это вообще лего из сотни рецептов...

Comment: вообще от производителя промышленного контроллера есть рекомендации как пользоваться тулчейном. Надо поставить Ubuntu 10, потом скачать и распокавать gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux.tar.bz2. Я ставлю Ubuntu 10 на виртуалбокс, но там команда wget не хочет работать. Какие-то проблемы с SSL. Что делать я уже не знаю. Может новую тему открыть с данным вопросом. Умаялся я уже )))

Comment: про wget не рабочий открывайте. Но что-то мне подсказывает что 3.5 для десятой убунты нормально не соберется.

Comment: @eri, похоже на то. На 12-й убунте тоже пока не получается. А какой можно 3-й питон поднять на 12-й убунте ?

Comment: а смысл? Если на контроллере 10ая. Там уже проще будет дебиан 9 накатить уже с питоном 3.5 и пробовать восстановить ПО разработчика на новой операционке. Если они драйвера не делали ядерных, то 85% что запустится

Comment: в том то и дело что на промышленном контроллере неизвестно какой линукс. Это производитель просто рекомендует кросс-компиляцию делать на 10-й убунте

Comment: Вобщем сделал все апдейты на 12-й убунте. Вроде wget заработал. Теперь когда пробую выполнить {./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared}   выводит сообщение : checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for python3.5... no
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.5 interpreter not found

Comment: Потыкай libc от него, версию надо знать, чтоб питон получился переносимый

Comment: @er , я по данному вопросу создал другую тему - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972311/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-python3-%D0%B2-ubuntu-12 . Проясни пожалуйста там что именно нужно сделать в части библы libc .

Answer (score 1):

В сообщении об ошибке написано:

> cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol:
>   PySlice_AdjustIndices

Т.е. из библиотеки *cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so* вызывается функция *PySlice_AdjustIndices*, которую линкер не может нигде найти. Причина, скорее всего, заключается в несовпадении версий библиотек, которые ожидаются в скрипте сборки и реальных библиотек на инструментальном компе.

Вы когда утилиту *./configure* перед сборкой запускали, не обратили внимания - никаких сообщений на эту тему не было ?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду когда выполняю ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared ? Нет, никаких сообщений не выводит.

Comment: я так понимаю в параметре "--build=" нужно писать "arm-linux-gnueabihf" а не ''x86_64-linux-gnu" ?

Comment: @Rashid-s *в параметре "--build=" нужно писать*. Там три(!) параметра, задающие платформы: 1) host: платформа, на которой выполняется *./configure* 2) build: платформа, на которой выполняется кросс-компиляция (НЕ обязана совпадать с п. 1.) 3) target: платформа, на которой будет выполняться собраный ELF. Если а.2 не задан, по дефаульту он совпадает с п.1.

Comment: я создал новую тему - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972311/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-python3-%D0%B2-ubuntu-12. Может поможете чем ?