# Кросс-компиляция Python3 в Ubuntu 12

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь сделать кросс-компиляцию Python 3.5.5 на Ubuntu 12 (в виртуалбокс), чтобы потом перенести на промышленный контроллер (в котором Линукс). Инструкция по вот этой ссылке - http://idiip.jiinii.com/cross-compile-python-3.html. При выполнении `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared`
командная строка выдает такое сообщение:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for python3.5... no
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.5 interpreter not found
```

Я так понимаю комилятор не может найти интерпретатор python3.5 ? Дак в Ubuntu 12 версии python3 вообще отсутствует. Как можно исправить ?

Comment: Так всё-таки, Вы на какой машине выполняете кросс-СБОРКУ ?! На x86_64 или на ARM ? Потому, как у Вас написано, что host - это x86_64, а build - arm... Вы ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬН выполняете ./configure на x86_64, а потом полученный Makefile перекладываете на ARM и там компилируете?!

Comment: @Sergey ,  я все делаю на виртуальной машине на ПК. Получается что нужно и хост и билд писать "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu". Попробовал выполнить ./configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared . Теперь другое сообщение выдает - prntscr.com/nf49cb .

Comment: Не понял - это что за сообщение: "prntscr.com/nf49cb" ?! Можно как-то в контексте его показать? Кто выдаёт - GCC, линкер или ещё кто?

Comment: А вообще-то, мне кажется, что проще взять готовую сборку питона для ARM. Например - тут: https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/arm/python

Comment: @Sergey , prntscr.com/nf49cb - это URL. Здесь не получается большой объем сообщений написать. Я сделал скриншот и выложил его. "prntscr.com/nf49cb"  (без кавычек) вбейте прямо в адресную строку браузера.

Comment: @Sergey , я разместил файл config.log сюда - https://pastebin.com/9Z8JzDiA

Comment: По обоим Вашим ссылкам я вижу одно и то же сообщение об ошибке: *configure:4122: error: in `/home/rashid/Python-3.5.5':
configure:4124: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details*. Только в первом случае - это скриншот, а во втором - нормальный текстовый файл.  Написано, что С-компиллер не может собрать ELF. А почему - надо смотреть  *config.log*. Значит то, что Вы показываете, это НЕ *config.log*.  Вот надо этот файл найти и искать в нём слово *Error*.

Comment: @Sergey , я параллельно создал тему на форуме - https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/14949072 . Крайний вариант файла config.log выложил сюда - https://pastebin.com/VTq3kDLW . Посмотрите пожалуйста, может чем поможете. Я обновил (а может и интсталлировал) sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf . Но все равно пока не получается.

Comment: Вот, что я вижу: 1) Для configure Вы указали --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf - ОК, всё понятно 2) Вы установили нужный компиллятор:  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf - ОК, всё хорошо 3) Но этот компиллятор не запускается! configure говорит, что "configure:4225: error: cannot run C compiled programs." Это в строке 109. Единственное объяснение, которое я могу придумать - компиллятор не в PATH.  Попробуйте в командной строке набрать *arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version*. Если скажет, что программа не найдена - пропишите его каталог в PATH.

Comment: Кстати, в той ветке, что Вы создали на linux.org.ru, там так прямо и написано *./configure: line 4024: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: command not found*. Это значит, что исполняемый модуль кросс-компиллера *arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*  не в PATH и *configure* его найти не может.

Comment: @Sergey , набираю команду _arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version_  мне отвечает что версия 4.6.3 . А как его в PATH прописать ?

Comment: @Rshid_s "мне отвечает что версия 4.6.3" - если отвечает, значит он уже прописан там. Значит дело не в этом...  Сейчас изложу самый "крайний" способ анализа таких проблем. Если не поможет, то тогда не знаю уже. Нужно сделать следующее:

Comment: 1) В сообщении об ошибке выдаётся номер строки файла *./configure*, где эта ошибка вылезла. Запоминаем этот номер. 2) Открываем файл *./configure* и ищем это место. 3) В этой строке должен стоять оператор печати сообщения об ошибке. А вот в нескольких строках **выше** идёт проверка, которая и дала отрицательный результат.  4) Пытаемся понять, что именно там проверялось. 5) Если поняли - пытаемся ликвидировать проблему.

Comment: Все эти проверки условий организованы одинаково: *./configure* создаёт некий тестовый файл с-программы и запускает компиллятор. Если компилятор выдал ошибки - проверка не пройдена и надо что-то исправлять. Вот Вы и должны понять - что именно проверялось. Как правило, проверяется наличие некоторых библиотек, опций и т.д...

Comment: @Sergey , все успешно получилось. Спасибо за помощь. Теперь нужно разобраться куда эти 4 папки ложить в промконтроллере? Как инсталлировать? Может по этому вопросу создать отдельную тему ?

Comment: @Sergey , если есть возможность можете помочь еще в одном вопросе? Проблему я обрисовал по ссылке - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980605/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потрудившись немного, разобрался что и как надо делать. Кому интересно, вот ссылка - https://github.com/Rashid-S/Cross-compile-Python-in-ARM-Linux-.

## Cross-compiling Python 3.5.5 for ARM-kernel on Linux

### Введение

В данном проекте последовательно изложены шаги сборки и кросс-компиляции интерпретатора Python 3.5.5 для ядра ARM. Кросс-компиляция проводилась на ОС Ubuntu 12.04, смонитированной на виртуальной машине. Интерпретатор предназначен для работы в ОС Linux на промышленном контроллере Adam-3600 (далее - PLC), но возможно применение и на других контроллерах (не знаю, не проверял).

### Зависимости

Провести инсталляцию обновлений

```
$ sudo apt-get install update
$ sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

Инсталлировать следующие библиотеки

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

### Кросс-компиляция и сборка

Выполнить последовательно команды

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir PythonSrc
$ cd PythonSrc
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.5/Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ tar zxf Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ mv Python-3.5.5 Python-3.5.5-host
$ cd Python-3.5.5-host
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonHost
$ make python Parser/pgen
$ make install
```

```
$ cd $HOME
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.5/Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ tar zxf Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ cd Python-3.5.5
$ export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
$ export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
$ export AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
$ export RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
$ export ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no
$ export ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no
$ export ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes
$ export PATH=/home/USER/PythonSrc/PythonHost/bin:$PATH
$ ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared
$ export HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/PythonSrc/Python-3.5.5-host/python3
$ export HOSTPGEN=$HOME/Python-3.5.5-host/Parser/pgen
$ export BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared"
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
$ export CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes
$ export HOSTARCH=arm-linux
$ export BUILDARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ make
$ make install
```

Скомпилированный проект должен появиться в директории `$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget/`

### Запуск интерпретатора на Adam-3600

В директории `$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget/` размещены четыре каталога - `/bin, /include, /lib, /share`. Я скопировал содержимое каждой директории в одноименные директории на PLC - `/usr/bin, /usr/include, /usr/lib, /usr/share` соотвественно.

Войти в директорий `/usr/bin`. Выполнить в командной строке

```
chmod +x python3.5
```

Далее

```
python3.5
```

В ответ в командной строке должно появиться приглашение интерпретатора

```
Python 3.5.5 (default, Apr 28 2019, 20:19:45)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```