# Ошибка импорта модуля ssl

Tags: linux, python-3.x, кросс-компиляция

Делаю кросс-компиляцию Python3.5.5 на виртуальной машине Ubuntu12. Затем переношу проект на промышленный контроллер. Интерпретатор Python в целом работает. Но есть проблема с модулем ssl.
При попытке импорта этого модуля мне выдает сообщение:

```
>>> import math
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
>>>
```

Вернулся на виртуальную машину и скомпилировал Openssl для ARM. Пользовался инструкцией вот по этой ссылке - https://assil.me/2017/09/30/cross-compile-openssl-arm-zynq.html . Думаю что получилось, потому как команда `file openssl` выводит сообщение:

```
openssl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0xf6d37a7af0fb5f9cedb9cf8ddaafbf5f60022129, not stripped
```

Вот что дальше делать? Где и что мне прописать в Configure при кросс-компиляции Python3.5.5 ?

Comment: Тулчейн какой? Из реп или как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl

Comment: @eri , здесь разместил пошагово как проводить кросс-компиляцию - https://github.com/Rashid-S/Cross-compile-Python-in-ARM-Linux- .

Answer (score 1):

Команда

```
>>> import ssl
```

выполняется не во время кросс-компилляции, а в тот момент, когда Вы уже запустили python (на ARM - я предполагаю?) и ввели её с клавиатуры на приглашение интерпретатора python.

Поэтому, процесс кросс-компиляции здесь не причём - он остался позади. Но собщениеи об ошибке

```
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
```

говорит о том, что тот интерпретатор python, который её выдал, не может найти модуль *ssl* в системных библиотеках. Файл *_ssl* и является флажком, сигнализирующим о том, что данный модуль **установлен** в системе.

Стандартный путь, для того, что бы установить этот модуль - выполнить команду

```
pip instsll ssl
```

pip: python installer program.  Однако, для того, что бы *pip* мог работать на Вашем ARM-е нормально, необходимо выполнение трёх условий.

1. Должен быть установлен сам pip.
2. Ваш ARM должен быть подключен к иНету.
3. *pip* должен быть настроен правильно на Ваше сетевое окружение. В смысле - мог бы достучаться до репозитария питоновских модулей.

Если всё это есть - проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Тут только компилятор, нужны ещё бинарные версии библиотек. Мне кажется ./configure сконфигурировал питон без поддержки ssl.

Попробуйте

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm
apt update
apt build-dep python3:arm
```

И заново собрать питон.
Хотя я б брал уже собранный из репозитария если не нужны какие-то опции.

Comment: я без этих команд и без ssl собираю. Работает на контроллере потом Питон. Просто появилась потребность в импорте ssl. Думаю нет необходимости в Ваших приведенных командах. Может я чего не догоняю (опыта мало) ?

Comment: у меня было что-то такое)

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем всем спасибо кто помог (особенно @Sergey ). В этой ссылке я описал что и как делать - https://github.com/Rashid-S/ADAM-3600

### 1. Введение

В данном проекте последовательно изложены шаги сборки и кросс-компиляции интерпретатора Python 3.5.5 для ядра ARM. Кросс-компиляция проводилась на ОС Ubuntu 12.04, смонитированной на виртуальной машине. Интерпретатор предназначен для работы в ОС Linux на промышленном контроллере Adam-3600 (далее - PLC), но возможно применение и на других контроллерах (не знаю, не проверял).

### 2. Зависимости

Провести инсталляцию обновлений

```
$ sudo apt-get install update
$ sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

Инсталлировать следующие библиотеки

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ sudo apt-get install dff
$ reboot
```

Проверить версию arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc командой `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version`. Версия должна быть 4.6.3.

### 3. Кросс-компиляция OpenSSL 1.0.1t

```
$ cd $HOME
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.1/openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.1t
$ ./Configure linux-generic32 shared --cross-compile-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ mkdir lib
$ cp ./*.{so,so.1.0.0,a,pc} ./lib
```

### 4. Кросс-компиляция и сборка Python-3.5.5

Выполнить последовательно команды

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir PythonSrc
$ cd PythonSrc
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.5/Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ tar zxf Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ mv Python-3.5.5 Python-3.5.5-host
$ cd Python-3.5.5-host
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonHost
$ make python Parser/pgen
$ make install
```

```
$ cd $HOME
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.5/Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ tar zxf Python-3.5.5.tgz
$ cd Python-3.5.5
$ export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
$ export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
$ export AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
$ export RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
$ export ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no
$ export ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no
$ export ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes
$ export PATH=/home/rashid/PythonSrc/PythonHost/bin:$PATH
$ export OPENSSL_ROOT=/home/rashid/openssl-1.0.1t
$ ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared
$ export HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/PythonSrc/Python-3.5.5-host/python3
$ export HOSTPGEN=$HOME/Python-3.5.5-host/Parser/pgen
$ export BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared"
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
$ export CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes
$ export HOSTARCH=arm-linux
$ export BUILDARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Откорректировать файлы `/usr/rashid/Python-3.5.5/Modules/Setup.dist` и `/usr/rashid/Python-3.5.5/setup.py`.
    Далее

```
$ make
$ make install
```

Скомпилированный проект должен появиться в директории `$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget/`

### 5. Запуск интерпретатора на Adam-3600

В директории `$HOME/PythonSrc/PythonTarget/` размещены четыре каталога - `/bin, /include, /lib, /share`. Я скопировал содержимое каждой директории в одноименные директории на PLC - `/usr/bin, /usr/include, /usr/lib, /usr/share` соотвественно, за исключением каталога `/lib/python3.5/test`, ввиду того что на PLC не так много места, да и надобности этого каталога нету.

Войти в директорий `/usr/bin`. Выполнить в командной строке

```
chmod +x python3.5
```

Далее

```
python3.5
```

В ответ в командной строке должно появиться приглашение интерпретатора

```
Python 3.5.5 (default, Apr 28 2019, 20:19:45)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```